# Jquery unidentified data return when post

Tags: php, jquery, html

```
<?php //load.php
$myid = $_POST['id'];
if($myid == 1){
    echo '1';
}else if($myid == 0){
    echo '0';
}
?>
<html>
    <input id="id" />
    <div id="result"></div>
    <input type="button" id="submit" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $('#submit').click( function(){
        var send = 'id=' + $('#id').val();
        $.post('load.php', send, function(data){
            if(data == 1){
                $('#result').html('Success');
            }else if(data == 0){
                $('#result').html('Failure');
            }else{
                $('#result').html('Unknow');
            }
        });
      });
    </script>
</html>
```

I test this script in some free host and it work but in my real host jquery unidentified data return and it alway show 'Unknow'.

When i change if(data == '1') it show 'Unknow' too

EX: input id = 1 click submit & data return is 'Unknow'

Why ?? I think this error from host, because i test it in some free host and it work, but now in my real host i got this error, how i can fix it ?

Comment: You are submitting it to itself so not only will it echo either 1 or 0 but also the rest of the html below the php

Comment: Also you aren't setting the val of the #id anywhere that I can tell

Comment: no, dont have any error on script

Comment: Given the above code what does `$('#id').val();` give you in a console?

Answer (score 2):

1. You use #result but have resurl
2. you need to not return anything but your value if myid is set. As Rob points out, you return `1<html>...` or `0<html>....`
3. For some reason, echo "1" actually returns data ="1 "; so a trailing space.

The reason is outlined here
http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/guidelines/general.html#php-closing-tag

> The PHP closing tag on a PHP document ?> is optional to the PHP parser. However, if used, any whitespace following the closing tag, whether introduced by the developer, user, or an FTP application, can cause unwanted output, PHP errors, or if the latter are suppressed, blank pages. For this reason, all PHP files should OMIT the closing PHP tag, and instead use a comment block to mark the end of file and it’s location relative to the application root. This allows you to still identify a file as being complete and not truncated.

Alternatively trim the result:

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://plungjan.name/SO/load.php)

```
<?php //load.php
if(isset($_POST["id"])){
  $myid = $_POST['id'];
  if($myid == "1"){
    echo "1";
  }else if($myid == "0"){
    echo "0";
  }
}
else {
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Post something</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $('#submit').click( function(){
    $.post('load.php', {"id":$('#id').val()}, function(data){
        window.console&&console.log(data,data=="1");
        var val = $.trim(data);
        if(val == "1"){
            $('#resurl').html('Success');
        }else if (val == "0"){
            $('#resurl').html('Failure');
        }else{
            $('#resurl').html('Unknown:[<span>'+val+'</span>]');
        }
    });
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="id" />
<div id="resurl"></div>
<input type="button" id="submit" />
</html>
<? } /* end php tag can be left out to avoid trailing spaces after it */
```

Comment: no all my script is work the problem is jquery unidentified data return and it alway show 'Unknow' in my host

Comment: If there is a space after last ?> it will be outputted too. Have a look at the code I posted